# C# Remoting - How to turn off CustomErrors

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, custom-errors

I getting the following error when I try to connect to my server app using remoting:

> *A problem seems to have occured whilst connecting to the remote server:
>
>   Server encountered an internal error. For more information, turn off customErrors in the server's .config file.*

This is the code on my server app:

```
TcpChannel tcpChannel = new TcpChannel(999);
MyRemoteObject remObj = new MyRemoteObject (this);
RemotingServices.Marshal(remObj, "MyUri");
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcpChannel);
```

It seems to work the first time, but unless the server app is restarted the error occurs.

I would guess something isn't being cleaned up properly but I'm not sure what as the customError is still on.

Any ideas where I start.  Thanks.

[EDIT] - Thanks to Gulzar, I modified my code above to the following and now the errors are shown:

```
RemotingConfiguration.CustomErrorsMode = CustomErrorsModes.Off;
TcpChannel tcpChannel = new TcpChannel(999);
MyRemoteObject remObj = new MyRemoteObject (this);
RemotingServices.Marshal(remObj, "MyUri");
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcpChannel);
```

Comment: Recently upgraded to 3.5 but i'm sure it was the same previously

Comment: @Hades it's a shame your edit is not an answer - as that worked for me but the two top voted answers did not.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For .Net 1.0/1.1 , you need a config file for remoting server

If you don't have a `<ServerEXE>.config` file, create one and have this in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <system.runtime.remoting>    
      <customErrors mode="off" />
   </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

For .Net 2.0, you can use [RemotingConfiguration.CustomErrorsMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.remotingconfiguration.customerrorsmode.aspx) property

Comment: You might like to correct the missing angle brackets in the above XML for newer users who might be confused.  Feel free to delete this comment once you've done so.

Comment: O should be capital in "off" ...without it being capital it wont work, I have literally pulled my hair for hours for that!!!

Answer (score 5):

In the server file, use:

```
RemotingConfiguration.CustomErrorsEnabled(bool);
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn off customErrors, open the `web.config file` on the server. If there is a `customErrors` tag, change it. If there isn't one, add it.

It should be `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` for this purpose.

If you are indeed using a custom error page, you will want to change this setting once you've found your problem.