# Turning off custom errors in Windows Service

Tags: app-config, custom-errors, .net-remoting

I have a Windows Service that uses .NET Remoting (yes I know remoting has been replaced by WCF but this is a legacy application).

When I run the service I get this:

> Exception Type: System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException Message:
>   Server encountered an internal error. For more information, turn off
>   customErrors in the server's .config file.

I have this in my application's config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.runtime.remoting>
        <!-- other settings go here -->
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

Oddly, I still get this exception. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/209257/17034

Comment: I saw that, but the config file changes they recommend don't work. Are you saying it's not possible and I have to hard-code this setting? I don't like doing that.